# CakePHP Model association for a social networking website

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm sorry. I thought about it but I can't come to a better title since I don't know how to describe this problem in one sentence.

Anyway, I am building a news feed just as Facebook where users can post a wall message and other users can comment on it.

I have 3 Tables in the database

`profiles` Table which contains the file name for their profile picture. `posts` table which contains details about posts and `comments` table for comments.

I have the below code in my `Post` model

```
    public $belongsTo = 'Profile';
    public $hasMany = 'Comment';
```

by doing that I can get the comments associated with each posts. But I am not able to get the profile picture from `profiles` table for "commenter". I tried

```
    public $belongsTo = 'Profile;
```

in the `Comment` model too but it's not working.

Comment: Share the `find` statement that is not working.

Comment: @AgRizzo `$this->Post->find('all');`

Comment: Did you read about [recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive)? Have you proven that `$this->Post->Comment->find();` will return the correct information? You need to provide more information to troubleshoot. Otherwise this question will eventually be closed because "it's not working" is too vague.